# Como habilitar o utf8_decode do PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, utf8-decode

Amigos, bom dia.
Criei uma maquina virtual no Ocean com Linux Ubuntu e PHP 5.6, porém ao subir os arquivos do sistema php, o servidor não identificou / interpretou a linha de comando:

```
echo utf8_encode($msg)
```

Existe alguma configuração que devo fazer nos arquivos de configuração do php para habilitar esta função ou instalar algo no servidor ?

Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instale o módulo **php5.6-xml** e reinicie o Apache:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml 
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Caso o problema persista, tente habilitar o módulo **xml2enc**:

```
sudo a2enmod xml2enc
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu apoio. Isso resolveu este problema. Porém agora, estou com outra questão: Tenho uma Hospedagem na Hostgator e essa criada no Digital Ocean. Na hostgator, os dados retornados da consulta do Mysql sem PHP estão retornando corretas, porém no Servidor da Ocean, os dados não retornam em UTF8... Teria alguma configuração para ser feita ?

Comment: Recomendo fazer outra pergunta, explicando os detalhes desse novo problema, como construiu a base de dados, até o formato de codificação de caracteres de seu editor de texto pode influenciar nisso, é muito amplo, tente fazer uma nova pergunta tentando ser mais específico ;)